# How to edit Jupyterlab User Interface

Tags: javascript, html, jupyter-lab

I am trying to edit the Jupyterlab Interface by adding a navbar however, the javascripts below that generates the page overrides my html navbar hence, I really need help on what I can do to resolve this. Thanks.

This is the jupyterlab static html file content (Location: /opt/tljh/user/share/jupyter/lab/static/index.html). The 2 javascripts are the ones generating the Jupyterlab page and the testingfile.html is my navbar that I included into the index.html file.

---

< script type="text/javascript" src="{{page_config.fullStaticUrl}}/main.43858584a06cc50f06b3.js">

< script type="text/javascript" src="{{page_config.fullStaticUrl}}/vendors~main.b22437b2abf9d5688fd7.js">

{% extends "testingfile.html" %}

---

[Jupyterlab navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vQDI.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to build a custom nav bar extension where you can add to or overwrite the original extension.

You can build an extension by following the tutorial [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_tutorial.html) where you will use the cookie cutter extension to build the navbar extension.

You will then be able to make a frontend plugin and for example specify the main-menu to add your own commands and styling.

```
const extension: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
  id: 'main-menu',
  autoStart: true,
  // Your code here


}
```